# Which is faster between window.btoa and Fildreader.readAsDataURL to get a base64string?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, blob, arraybuffer

I am trying to decide a faster algorithm between the two below, if there is any.

1. Get `xmlHttpRequest` as `arrayBuffer` - Convert to a new `Uint8Array` - `window.btoa` to convert to a **base64 string**.
2. Get `xmlHttpRequest` as `blob` - Use FileReader `readAsDataURL` to have a **base64 string** inside DtatURL string only to drop DataURL prefix on the server side.

Plus, is there any way I can get a mime type from an xmlHttpRequest of the type `arraybuffer` wihtout FileReader like the `Blob` equivalent with `xhr.response.type`?

Comment: Not certain what requirement is? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get a base 64 string to send it over an AJAX request.

Comment: _"I am trying to get a base 64 string to send it over an AJAX request."_ What are you trying to get a `base64` string from?

Comment: Blob is going to be faster, user-land arrayBuffer conversion is slower than FileReader's internals.

Comment: ajax responses typically have a "Content-Type" header you can read to get the MIME

Comment: Do a performance test (also btoa works on strings = caveats)